# Why QO choses clustered index-scan vs table-scan?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

If I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tTable
```

where `tTable` does not contain any indexes a table-scan happens, as expected. If I add a clustered index on some column then QO decides to use clustered index scan on this query. Why? Why is clustered-index-scan preferred instead of table-scan in this case?

Answer (score 0):

> If I add a clustered index on some column then QO decides to use clustered index scan on this query

because when you create a clustered index on a table,data in table is rearranged in index order..so table it self is clustered index.This is also the reason why you can't have two clustered indexes on same table

To summarize,when you create a clustered index,there is only one structure ,not two(clustered index and table)

Answer (score 0):

The query is "give me all rows and all columns" which means "read every row" which is a scan

There is nothing to do an index seek on, because there is no WHERE clause.
Unlike this:

```
 SELECT * FROM tTable WHERE PrimaryClusteredKeyValue = 45
```

Then this may use a nonclustered seek followed by a clustered key lookup or it may still scan the clustered index because you ask for all columns. It depends on how many rows `gbn` will match

```
 SELECT * FROM tTable WHERE NonClusteredOtherColumnValue = 'gbn'
```